# Is there a way of adding extra information to a graph that is saved using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

So I have created a simulation of the orbits of Venus, Earth, Mars and Jupiter around the Sun using turtle in Python. Below is my code:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import turtle
from turtle import *

...

def loop(bodies, earth):
    timestep = 3600 * 24 * 7
    step = 1
    earth_years = -1

    final_data = []
    for step in range(0, max_step + 1):
        update_info(step, bodies)

        if 0.98 <= earth.px / au <= 1.00 and -0.05 <= earth.py / au <= 0.05:
            earth_years += 1
            turtle.clear()
            turtle.penup()
            turtle.goto(-450, 350)
            turtle.pendown()
            turtle.color("white")
            turtle.hideturtle()
            turtle.write(f"Earth Years: {earth_years}", font=("Calibri", 20, "normal"))

        force = {}
        for body in bodies:
            total_fx = total_fy = 0.0
            for other in bodies:
                if body is other:
                    continue
                fx, fy = body.attraction(other)
                total_fx += fx
                total_fy += fy

            force[body] = (total_fx, total_fy)

        for body in bodies:
            fx, fy = force[body]
            body.vx += fx / body.mass * timestep
            body.vy += fy / body.mass * timestep

            if body.name != "Sun":
                body.px += body.vx * timestep
                body.py += body.vy * timestep
                body.goto(body.px * scale, body.py * scale)

        for body in bodies:
            text_values = f"Week: {step:3}  {body.name:4}   Position ={body.px/au:6.2f} {body.py/au:6.2f}  Velocity ={body.vx:10.2f} {body.vy:10.2f}"
            final_data.append(text_values)

        file.write(str(final_data) + "\n")
        final_data = []

    file.close()
    graph(earth_years, save_as_file=False)

...

def graph(earth_years, save_as_file=True):
    sim_data = open("C:/[FolderPath]/planetaryOrbits.txt", "r")
    plt.xlabel("AU")
    plt.ylabel("AU")
    plt.title("Orbits of Venus, Earth, Mars and Jupiter around the Sun")
    plt.axis([-6, 6, -6, 6])
    plt.grid()

    celestial_coordinates = []

    for z in sim_data:
        i = z.split()
        xs = float(i[5])
        ys = float(i[6])
        xv = float(i[16])
        yv = float(i[17])
        xe = float(i[27])
        ye = float(i[28])
        xm = float(i[38])
        ym = float(i[39])
        xj = float(i[49])
        yj = float(i[50])
        total = [xs, ys, xv, yv, xe, ye, xm, ym, xj, yj]
        celestial_coordinates.append(total)

    celestial_coordinates = list(zip(*celestial_coordinates))

    plt.plot(celestial_coordinates[0], celestial_coordinates[1], color = "yellow", marker = "o", label = "Sun")
    plt.plot(celestial_coordinates[2], celestial_coordinates[3], color = "purple", label = "Venus")
    plt.plot(celestial_coordinates[4], celestial_coordinates[5], color = "blue", label = "Earth")
    plt.plot(celestial_coordinates[6], celestial_coordinates[7], color = "red", label = "Mars")
    plt.plot(celestial_coordinates[8], celestial_coordinates[9], color = "green", label = "Jupiter")
    plt.legend(loc="upper right", fontsize=10)

    if save_as_file:
        try:
            # Show the AU values for each planet (only in the saved file)
            planet_au = {
                "Venus": max(celestial_coordinates[2]),
                "Earth": max(celestial_coordinates[4]),
                "Mars": max(celestial_coordinates[6]),
                "Jupiter": max(celestial_coordinates[8])
            }
            for planet, max_planet_au in planet_au.items():
                planet_color = {"Venus": "purple", "Earth": "blue", "Mars": "red", "Jupiter": "green"}
                if planet == "Venus":
                    plt.text(-0.68, +1.8, f"{max_planet_au:.2f} AU", fontsize=10, color=planet_color[planet], bbox=dict(facecolor="white", edgecolor="none"))
                elif planet == "Earth":
                    plt.text(+1.69, -0.15, f"{max_planet_au:.2f} AU", fontsize=10, color=planet_color[planet], bbox=dict(facecolor="white", edgecolor="none"))
                elif planet == "Mars":
                    plt.text(-2.65, -1.6, f"{max_planet_au:.2f} AU", fontsize=10, color=planet_color[planet], bbox=dict(facecolor="white", edgecolor="none"))
                elif planet == "Jupiter":
                    plt.text(-3.6, +3.1, f"{max_planet_au:.2f} AU", fontsize=10, color=planet_color[planet])
            # Show the total Earth years (only in the saved file)
            earth_position = celestial_coordinates[4], celestial_coordinates[5]
            earth_orbit_completion = math.atan2(earth_position[1][-1], earth_position[0][-1]) / (2 * math.pi)
            plt.text(-2.35, -3.21, f"Total Earth Years: {earth_years + 1 + earth_orbit_completion:.2f}", fontsize=12, color="black", bbox=dict(facecolor="white", edgecolor="none"))
            plt.savefig("C:/[FolderPath]/planetaryOrbits.png")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error saving the file: {e}")
    try:
        plt.show()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error showing the graph: {e}")
```

(Currently the graph does not save as I've set the "save_as_file" to `False`)

Essentially what I want is when the simulation finishes for an interactive graph to show up (which is what happens), but I also want the graph to be saved with additional information that is not displayed on the interactive graph. So I want the interactive graph to just have the orbits and legend, but the saved file to have the AU of each planet and the total Earth years added on.

I've tried different methods and I either get both graphs displaying the same information, or have to choose whether to display the graph with just the orbits and legend or save the graph with the additional AU and total Earth years.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Plot the simplified view, show it, then after closing the interactive window add everything else and finally use `savefig`

```
In [8]: plt.cla()
   ...: plt.plot()
   ...: plt.show()
   ...: plt.title('Title')
   ...: plt.savefig('Figure2.png', dpi=185)
   ...: !qiv Figure2.png
```

(`qiv` is a simple image viewer, substitute another one according to availability/preferences).

Comment: Does closing the window not destroy the figure?

Comment: @RuthC ,,, try my code! (I've tested it in IPython)

Answer (score 0):

If you keep track of the extra artists you added, then you can simply remove them again after your `savefig` call:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot([0, 1])

save_as_file = True

if save_as_file:
    extra_artists = []
    extra_artists.append(ax.text(0, 0, 'foo'))
    extra_artists.append(ax.text(1, 0, 'bar'))

    plt.savefig("test.png")

    for artist in extra_artists:
        artist.remove()
        
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain the interactive graph and add additional information to your savefile, you can use pickle to save the results:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle as pickle

# Plot simple sinus function
fig = plt.figure()
x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y)

extra_data = [1,2,3]
# Save figure handle to disk
import pickle
with open('figure.pickle', 'wb') as f: # should be 'wb' rather than 'w'
    pickle.dump([fig,extra_data], f)
plt.close(fig)



# Load figure handle from disk    
with open('figure.pickle','rb') as file:
    loaded_fig,loaded_extra_data = pickle.load(file)
    
plt.show()
```